# Jssor slider with require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, jssor

I attempted to find an answer to my question with the search engine but I was unable to.
I'm using [jssor slider](http://www.jssor.com/) in my backbone project with require.js. Anyone can tell what `deps` and `exports` of `Jssor slider` should I configure in `shim: {}` of main.js

That is that I tried but didn't work :

```
 "jssor" : {
        exports : "Jssor"
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tried yet, what about the following idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        paths: {
            //path of jssor slider.mini.js
            "jssor": '/jssor.slider.mini.js'
        },
        shim: {
            'jssor': {
                exports: '$JssorSlider$'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, You are so clever! Could you tell me, how could you know that is `$JssorSlider$`? I saw only `(function(g,f,b,d,c,e,z){/*! Jssor */
    $Jssor$=g.$Jssor$=g.$Jssor$ ...... ` in `jssor.slider.min.js` file.

Comment: Once jssor.slider.mini.js is loaded, you can access a global variable $JssorSlider$, which is attached to window, it looks like window.$JssorSlider$. Also, $Jssor$ and window.$Jssor$ are available as well.